# simplest way to generate xml in python

Tags: python, xml

I have a defaultdict(list).. So, data structure of following format:

```
1:[1,2,3,4,5]
2:[2,3,4]
```

I want to generate the following xml

```
<html>
<page>
<src>1</src>
<links>
   <link>1</link>
   <link>2</link>
    ...
    <link>5</link>
</links>
</page>

<page>
<src>2</src>
<links>
   <link>2</link>
   <link>3</link>
    <link>4</link>
</links>
</page>
<html>
```

And then write an indented xml to file

Comment: are the xml tags fixed? looks more like a html.

Comment: Check out this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4470210/25097](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4470210/25097). ``lxml.builder.E`` is super-easy to use for this kind of thing.

Comment: @unixer: yepp they are fixed

Comment: Speaking as someone who does not know how to use the xml libraries of python, your question seems straightforward to implement with two nested for loops, if you are reasonable sure your scope won't grow for this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import Tag


d = {1: [1,2,3,4,5], 2: [2,3,4]}

root = Tag(name='html')
for key, values in d.iteritems():
    page = Tag(name='page')
    src = Tag(name='src')
    src.string = str(key)
    page.append(src)

    links = Tag(name='links')
    for value in values:
        link = Tag(name='link')
        link.string = str(value)
        links.append(link)

    page.append(links)
    root.append(page)

print root.prettify()
```

prints:

```
<html>
 <page>
  <src>
   1
  </src>
  <links>
   <link>
    1
   </link>
   <link>
    2
   </link>
   <link>
    3
   </link>
   <link>
    4
   </link>
   <link>
    5
   </link>
  </links>
 </page>
 <page>
  <src>
   2
  </src>
  <links>
   <link>
    2
   </link>
   <link>
    3
   </link>
   <link>
    4
   </link>
  </links>
 </page>
</html>
```

Comment: Anyway, we can indent the format properly like <src>1</src> in same line??

Comment: @Fraz it's just a beautifulsoup prettifier, you can customize the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) template and render it:

```
from jinja2 import Template


data = {1:[1,2,3,4,5], 2:[2,3,4]}

html = """<html>
    {% for key, values in data.iteritems() %}
        <page>
        <src>{{ key }}</src>
        <links>
            {% for value in values %}
               <link>{{ value }}</link>
            {% endfor %}
        </links>
        </page>
    {% endfor %}
<html>"""

template = Template(html)
print template.render(data=data)
```

prints:

```
<html>
        <page>
        <src>1</src>
        <links>
               <link>1</link>
               <link>2</link>
               <link>3</link>
               <link>4</link>
               <link>5</link>
        </links>
        </page>

        <page>
        <src>2</src>
        <links>
               <link>2</link>
               <link>3</link>
               <link>4</link>
        </links>
        </page>
<html>
```